# An error about java.lang.ArithmeticException in hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

there is an error that occurred in my code, and I can not find the reason. The exception log is:

> *HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero], SQL: update TVSENSORINFO set SENSORTYPE=?, TEMP=?, REPORTTIMESPAN=?, SENSORSTATE=?, V=?, AddTime=?, UpdateTime=?, LOCATIONID=?, RSSI=?, VISHIS=? where SENSORNUM=?*.

And that I was doing an update to a table in MSSQL. The code is:

```
    public void saveOrUpdate(Collection<?> collections) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tran = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            Callable<Boolean> saveOrUpdateCallable = new Callable<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call() {
                    try {
                        for (var item : collections){
                            session.saveOrUpdate(item);
                        }
                        tran.commit();
                        return true;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        LogManager.writeError("HibernateUtil, saveOrUpdateCallable!" + " Size of collections:" + collections.size(), e);
                        tran.rollback();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            };
            TimeoutUtil.<Boolean>process(saveOrUpdateCallable, 20, "HibernateUtil-saveOrUpdate");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogManager.writeError("Exception at HibernateUtil, saveOrUpdate!" + " Size of collections:" + collections.size(), e);
            tran.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.clear();
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't share a session with a different thread. You have to create a session per thread.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to move the Session.